# Is there a "JOIN" query to show the first name and last name of the employees who do not work in the same locations with their manager

Tags: sql

I am stuck on a query to find employees who do not work at the same location as their manager based on the attached schema.

[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfYWm.png)

Comment: Hello @M11CH, it would be nice to know more things about your problem like: what database do you use ? And what did you try so far, what is giving you a problem in your query? Also, some sample data would be nice (what you get and what you expect...). Give it a try and edit this question into a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join four tables, as shown below:

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  ed.location_id as employee_location_id,
  m.employee_id as manager_id,
  md.location_id as manager_location_id
from employees e
join departments ed on e.department_id = ed.department_id
join employees m on e.manager_id = e.employee_id
join departments md on m.department_id = md.department_id
where ed.location_id <> md.location_id
```